# Is there a generic delay function which can be run in between tkinter button colour changes so that the colour changes happen in sequence?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

```
...code above...
def readtime():
  >>>HERE IS WHAT I AM MISSING<<<

#defining moves for knight at board positions:

def A8():  
  readtime()
  buttonA8['bg'] = 'green'
  readtime()
  buttonB6['bg'] = 'yellow'
  readtime()
  buttonD5['bg'] = 'yellow'
  readtime()
  buttonE7['bg'] = 'yellow'
  readtime()
  buttonG8['bg'] = 'yellow'
  readtime()
  buttonH6['bg'] = 'yellow'
...code continues...
```

I've tested it and it works except for the delay i.e. it does everything I want it to do for each function it just happens all at once instead of one colour change at a time with half second breaks. I haven't included the entire code because this is only a small section, however it is crucial for the whole program to work as intended. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you want the change takes place immediately, add `root.update_idletasks()` (assume `root` is the root window) before the sleep or delay inside `readtime()`.

Answer (score 1):

You want `tkinter.after()`

```
def readtime():
    tkinter.after(1000, func=<DO STUFF HERE>)  # wait 1sec, then do stuff
```

the `func` parameter can be any callable (i.e, function), or a lambda (an anonymous function).

You could honestly also use `None` as the func argument since you only care about the delay: `tkinter.after(1000, None)` but this isn't a typical usage and your code will still be fairly repetitive.

*Quick addendum*:
If you don't need your `readtime()` function to do anything other than delay, you can eliminate it entirely and just call `tkinter.after(1000, None)` directly instead

```
tkinter.after(1000, None)
buttonA8['bg'] = 'green'
tkinter.after(1000, None)
buttonB6['bg'] = 'yellow'
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier - I took a break from python over the weekend. I tried this and it just waits the total time of all of the 'tkinter.after(1000, None)' and then afterwards (60 seconds later) it changes all the colours at once. It simply 2ingores the order of the code and runs all of the .after lines first and then the button changes later.

Comment: What happens if you wrap the calls to `after()` in a function like you had initially?